# Comparing PHP's NumberFormatter::formatCurrency results

Tags: php, utf-8, locale, number-formatting, currency-formatting

I'm having problems unit testing a library that uses NumberFormatter::formatCurrency. After some trial and error, I've narrowed down the problem to this test case:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider getLocales()
 */
public function test($locale, $expected)
{
    $number_formatter = new \NumberFormatter($locale, \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
    $actual = $number_formatter->formatCurrency(3000.05, 'EUR');
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual, $locale.' failed');
}

public function getLocales()
{
    return array(
        array('en_US', '€3,000.05'),
        array('fr_FR', '3 000,05 €'),
        array('de_DE', '3.000,05 €'),
    );
}
```

The results are:

```
fr_FR failed
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
Expected :3 000,05 €
Actual   :3 000,05 €


de_DE failed
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
Expected :3.000,05 €
Actual   :3.000,05 €
```

As you can see the failed tests seem to have identical strings, so it should be a problem of locale.

I've tried comparing with strcoll, setting the locale before the comparison, and other combinations with no luck.

I guess it's something to do with different utf-8 codes in each language. But how can I compare those strings then?

Comment: In order to pass the tests, I had actually to echo the $actual result, and then copy and paste over the expected values from the dataProvider. But that is not an acceptable solution in my opinion.

Comment: yes the problem is that the space is encoded with different encodings... istead of hex value 20 you get a0

Comment: I know this problem is a little old, but I am actually having a similar issue using NumberFormatter. What I was able to decipher is that, as of now, `NumberFormatter::formatCurrency()` is actually returning a string with hidden characters in it, hence why they appear to be the same but are actually of different string lengths. I was able to find this out by running the expected and actual results through `utf8encode`. Unfortuatenly, I haven't been able to find a clean solution yet. Were you ever able to come up with one?

Comment: I did what I explained in the first comment, and then I just forgot about it. Sorry I cannot be of more help.

Comment: @GrahamS., did you find a solution meanwhile? I am struggeling with the same problem currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. PHP's NumberFormatter inserts a special space character, the so-called No-Break-Space (maybe you know `&nbsp;`).

if you convert the read value

```
str_replace("\xc2\xa0", " ", $actual);
```

everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is locale- or version-dependent, but in my testing I found that it is not the `NBSP` character, but the `NNBSP` character.

- `NBSP`: `NO-BRAKE-SPACE`, UTF-8 `0xC2 0xA0` or UTF-16 `0x00A0`
- `NNBSP`: `NARROW NO-BRAKE-SPACE`, UTF-8 `0xE2 0x80 0xAF` or UTF-16 `0x202F`

It can be removed like this:

```php
str_replace("\u{202F}", "", $string);
```